# character array overflowing by sprintf

Tags: c, arrays, embedded, printf

I am using char array[6];
I am converting a float variable to string using sprintf as follows..

```
sprintf(array,"%f\0",floatvar);
```

and i am writing char array on LCD.

Problem is my array size is only 6 bytes, but it is printing "00000.00000" 11 byte of data. Array size is restricted to 6 bytes. But How the array overflowing in this case?

Comment: There are actually valid reasons to write `\0` in a string literal (eg WinAPI's file dialog filter strings). This is not one of them.

Answer (score 2):

The `sprintf` function expects that you provide a big enough buffer to hold all of its output. Otherwise your code causes undefined behaviour.

Your code would not produce `00000.00000` either; if the value is between `0` and `1` then the output will start with `0.` . Perhaps you used a different format string in your real code.

---

With `%f` it is not possible to constrain the output solely via format string modifiers. To be safe, you can use `snprintf`:

```
snprintf(array, 6, "%f", floatvar);
```

If your system does not have `snprintf` available then I would suggest downloading a freeware implementation of `vsnprintf`.

As a last resort you could use `sprintf` with a lot of checking:

```
if ( floatvar < 0.f || floatvar >= 1.f )
    exit.....;

sprintf(array, 6, "%.3f", floatvar);
```

The `.3` means that at most 3 characters will show after the decimal point; and since we did a range check that means the start will be `0.` , for a total of 5 output characters plus null terminator.

To be on the safe side I'd suggest temporarily outputting to a large buffer, using `strlen` to check what was written, and then copying to your 6-byte buffer if it did write correctly.

NB. `"%f\0"` is strange; string literals are strings and so they end in `'\0'` already. `"%f\0"` ends in two null terminators.